# How to get response header in react native android?

Tags: javascript, android, xmlhttprequest, react-native, response

Hello i want to get response header after fetch POST request. I tried to debug to see what inside `response` with `console.log(response)`. I can get response bodies from `responseData` but i have no idea how to get the header. I want to get both header and the body. Please help. thanks:)

Here's the example what i've done:

```js
   fetch(URL_REGISTER, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        if(responseData.success == 1){
          this.setState({
            message1: responseData.msg,
          });
        }
        else{
          this.setState({
            message1: responseData.msg,
          });
        }
      })
      .done();
    },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*you can do like this*

```
  fetchData() {
  var URL_REGISTER = 'https://www.example.com';
  fetch(URL_REGISTER, {method: 'POST',body: formData})
      .then(
          function(response) {
              console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
              console.log(response.headers.get('Date'));

              console.log(response.status);
              console.log(response.statusText);
              console.log(response.type);
              console.log(response.url);
              if (response.status !== 200) {
                  console.log('Status Code: ' + response.status);
                  return;
              }

              // Examine the text in the response
              response.json().then(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
              });
          }
      )
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Fetch Error', err);
      });
}
```

*Read More about fetch: [Introduction to fetch()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)*

Comment: Thanks, that's help me a lot :)

Comment: It is also important to note that due to [W3 Standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology) only `Cache-Control`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified` and `Pragma` are accessible when making requests outside the domain.

Comment: How can we achieve same if we are using AXIOS

Answer (score 2):

You can take the headers from `response.headers`

```
fetch(URL_REGISTER, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers); //Returns Headers{} object
}
```

Comment: i tried to edit like this `.then((response) => {console.log(response.headers); response.json()})` ,  but when i run it, it show me the error because it not read `response.json()` . Any ideas?

Comment: @sptra, `.json()` returns a promise, so to get the response as JSON you need to handle the promise: `.then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.headers);
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (json) {
      console.log(json); 
    }).catch...`

Answer (score 1):

You should return response.json() like 
 `return response.json();`