# How to get Online Current Date and Time in React Native

Tags: android, date, react-native, time

I tried to get current time and date by this command

```
new Date()
```

But when I change the time on my phone, It changed base on the time on my phone.

I want to get the current time and date in real time. Please help me. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the real time using an api over the internet like this for example:

```
 https://timezonedb.com/api
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really help me!

Answer (score 2):

you could try the following code

```
fetchData() {
  var URL_REGISTER = 'https://www.google.com';
  fetch(URL_REGISTER, {method: 'POST',body: formData})
      .then(
          function(response) {
              console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
              console.log(response.headers.get('Date'));

              console.log(response.status);
              console.log(response.statusText);
              console.log(response.type);
              console.log(response.url);
              if (response.status !== 200) {
                  console.log('Status Code: ' + response.status);
                  return;
              }

              // Examine the text in the response
              response.json().then(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
              });
          }
      )
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Fetch Error', err);
      });
}
```

references: [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094103/how-to-get-response-header-in-react-native-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the real time making a request to any reliable server.
You will get `Date` header in the server's response (Eg. `Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2018 10:33:14 GMT`)

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date().getTime();
```

You can use whatever you want to replace getTime() to following one :

```
/** Returns a string representation of a date. The format of the string depends on the locale. */
toString(): string;
/** Returns a date as a string value. */
toDateString(): string;
/** Returns a time as a string value. */
toTimeString(): string;
/** Returns a value as a string value appropriate to the host environment's current locale. */
toLocaleString(): string;
/** Returns a date as a string value appropriate to the host environment's current locale. */
toLocaleDateString(): string;
/** Returns a time as a string value appropriate to the host environment's current locale. */
toLocaleTimeString(): string;
/** Returns the stored time value in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. */
valueOf(): number;
/** Gets the time value in milliseconds. */
getTime(): number;
/** Gets the year, using local time. */
getFullYear(): number;
/** Gets the year using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCFullYear(): number;
/** Gets the month, using local time. */
getMonth(): number;
/** Gets the month of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCMonth(): number;
/** Gets the day-of-the-month, using local time. */
getDate(): number;
/** Gets the day-of-the-month, using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCDate(): number;
/** Gets the day of the week, using local time. */
getDay(): number;
/** Gets the day of the week using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCDay(): number;
/** Gets the hours in a date, using local time. */
getHours(): number;
/** Gets the hours value in a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCHours(): number;
/** Gets the minutes of a Date object, using local time. */
getMinutes(): number;
/** Gets the minutes of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCMinutes(): number;
/** Gets the seconds of a Date object, using local time. */
getSeconds(): number;
/** Gets the seconds of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCSeconds(): number;
/** Gets the milliseconds of a Date, using local time. */
getMilliseconds(): number;
/** Gets the milliseconds of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getUTCMilliseconds(): number;
/** Gets the difference in minutes between the time on the local computer and Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
getTimezoneOffset(): number;
```

Comment: If i change the device date manually, it gives me only device date:(