# Get secured current date in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Does someone know how to get an actual country date without any possibility for the user to fake it ? This date is supposed to perform security check and I don't know if using new Date() is safe ? Can we modify the date via phone settings to fake the result of new Date() ?

Comment: You can never trust the client device or software.

Comment: Alright thank you and do you have a solution to get date from web for example ?

Comment: If you're using something like a TOTP scheme, then making the client date wrong is still possible but the client will be denied access (because the codes will be wrong).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot trust the date on the device, **particularly** if you're using the date for gatekeeping as then the user has a particular incentive to make the date on the device incorrect.

Instead, if you really need to (mostly) trust the date, you need to query it over the network from somewhere not under the user's control, such as [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/services/internet-time-service-its).

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll do it with a cloud function, or you maybe know a better solution or package ? I had a look on NIST but I don't see how  I can implement it with react native.

Comment: @Joris - I don't know of a specific one, no.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question [How to get Online Current Date and Time in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866522/how-to-get-online-current-date-and-time-in-react-native/53866622)

where someone is giving this API https://timezonedb.com/api