# How to get exact time in React Native/Expo

Tags: react-native, time, expo

I'm working on an application where timestamps are super important. Right now, I'm simply using Date.now(), but the values I'm getting are off. On an IPhone 13, time.gov tells me I'm accurate to about 15ms, but on a Galaxy A32, time.gov says that I'm accurate to about 330ms. Is there any way to 'force' the clock on a phone to sync, or do I need to implement some sort of NTP time sync routine?

Comment: As time accuracy is a serious concern. Rely on device time  should be not efficient. Can you try to use remote server API for get current time -https://timeapi.io/swagger/index.html

Comment: How would I compensate for the latency incurred while getting the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Online Current Date and Time in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866522/how-to-get-online-current-date-and-time-in-react-native)